# Segmentation fault when calling strcpy

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy, strncpy

I was trying to use `strncpy` and then `strcpy` and vice versa, but I kept receiving a segmentation fault during runtime. I thought this was because of an logical error in the functions, but I switched their places and only the first one would execute.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c = ' ', sentence[50], *pointer_to_string;
    pointer_to_string = &sentence[0];
    int index = 0;

    printf("Please enter a sentence:");
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        sentence[index] = c;
        index++;
    }
    sentence[index] = '\0';

    char *string_copy1, *string_copy2;

    strncpy(string_copy1, pointer_to_string, 5);
    printf("strncpy(string_copy1, pointer_to_string, 5):\n");
    printf("%s\n", string_copy1);

    strcpy(string_copy2, pointer_to_string);
    printf("strcpy(string_copy2, pointer_to_string):\n");
    printf("%s\n", string_copy2);
}
```

Comment: Try to compile with `-g` flag and use valgrind while execute the program: `valgrind ./a.out` => you'll get more informations

Comment: ` char *string_copy1, *string_copy2;` does not initialise either of those variables. So neither of them points at a valid memory location. Then you use str(n)cpy to overwrite the contents of an array of chars -- that is, a "string" -- but the pointer you give it does not point at such an array. So undefined behaviour ensues.

Comment: You need to initialize `string_copy1` and `string_copy2;` before you use them. Using malloc find out how here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc

Comment: You can also use `malloc()` on `char *` to allocate memory for them and get ride of seg faults.  `string_copy1 = malloc(50*sizeof(char));`
 `string_copy2 = malloc(50*sizeof(char));` and `pointer_to_string = malloc(50*sizeof(char));
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html):

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The first argument is a pointer to the destination buffer. But your pointers are not initialized:

```
char *string_copy1, *string_copy2;
```

Therefore, pointers contain some garbage values. And `strcpy()` writes to the memory that does not belong to your program. It causes [segmentation fault](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346849/8678309).

Do

```
char string_copy1[50] = { 0 };
char string_copy2[50] = { 0 };
```

Filling them with zeros is neccessary to avoid problems with `strncpy()`:

> If there is no null byte among the first `n` bytes of `src`, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated.

Comment: How do I initialize them?  And the first function with strncopy worked.

Comment: Thank you, I pointed the pointers to new character arrays, and the functions worked.

Comment: Don't use strncpy(). It doesn't do what you might expect, and it is in fact useless except for setting fixed-width fields in databases, which is the use for which it was designed.

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean strncpy prevents overflowing the destination buffer.

Comment: But it doesn't add a nul. So it is only useful if you have a non-nul terminated string of fixed width, which is never, except in certain database apps.

Comment: The other problem with `strncpy()` is that if you have a big buffer and a short string to copy into it, every otherwise unused byte of the buffer is set to a null byte — it always writes to every position in the destination string, even though it doesn't guarantee to null terminate it either.  It's a peculiar and hard to use function.  If it is any consolation, `strncat()` is even harder to use right and therefore more deadly; don't use that, either.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Simply put, `strncpy()` always writes `n` bytes.